# How to add a file in the same repository having same folder name in github

Tags: android, json, git

I added a JSON file to my GitHub account and I need to access it in my android music player app and for the image, I need to put the image in the same folder but whenever I put it in the same repository it generates a different link. 
The link for my JSON raw file is:

[Link to my JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zakharhabib/hello-world/df50ba624b8d255f19fa723a69b3e9e685d5e858/musiclibrary.json)

I need an image in the same folder with the link:

I need the same link for my image just need 'album_art_3.jpg' at the end of the link instead of 'musiclibrary.JSON'

[These are the files in my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUOrX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are linking to your file with the raw git commit hash. If you added the image and json file in different commits, their raw git commit hash value in which they were added is different. The commit hash you're using to link to the json file didn't even have the image file at that commit point, so you're pointing to a non-existent file if you try to point to the image file with the same commit hash.

Instead of the commit hash, use the branch name on which both exist, in this case 'master', as in

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zakharhabib/hello-world/master/musiclibrary.json

and

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zakharhabib/hello-world/master/album_art_3.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me with the concept and understanding what a stupid mistake i was making. Once again thank you so much.